# Append YouTube videos to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to embed videos in a span in two different ways but the video is not displayed on the span.

First way:

```
my_span = $('<span>').attr(word.html).addClass('v'+ weight + " " + custom_class);
                   my_span.append('<embed src="'+ link +'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> </embed>');
```

Second way:

```
my_span = $('<span>').attr(word.html).addClass('v'+ weight + " " + custom_class);
               my_span.append('<iframe src="'+ link +'" "></iframe>');
```

The css class is like this:

```
span.v2 {
  display:block;  
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
}
```

Can you please guide me to the solution? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show the code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Since I haven't ever used the jsfiddle.net, I will sign up and then try to create a small sample of code.

Answer (score 1):

`$('<span>')` is not a valid selector. you need to use `$('span')`

Try this

```
my_span = $('span');
my_span.attr(word.html).addClass('v'+ weight + " " + custom_class);
my_span.append('<embed src="'+ link +'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> </embed>');
```

Comment: The same code with $('<span>') works for images. Nevertheless, I followed your advice but didn't return even the blank span. Thank you anyway.